# How to destruct props when it's only existed react

Tags: reactjs, react-props

```
const Sample = ({card}) = > {
 const {createdAt, title} = card;

 const dateFormat = isThisYear(createdAt) ? 'MMM d' : 'MMM d, yyyy';

 return(
   <Child title={title} />
 )
}
```

I got an error message saying `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'createdAt' of 'card' as it is undefined.`

Can I get `createdAt, title` only card exists or card is also passed from the parent component, so get `createdAt, title` if the card is passed?

```
const Sample = ({card}) = > {
 
  const dateFormat = isThisYear(card?.createdAt) ? 'MMM d' : 'MMM d, yyyy';
 
  return(
    <Child title={card?.title} />
  )
 }
```

I could not destruct props and add `?` like above but if there is a way to destruct props and get `createdAt, title` only card exists, I'd be happy to know!

Comment: Where does `card` come from? I don't see it defined anywhere

Comment: @Nick Updated my code, card is props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to provide a default value of an empty object for your `card` prop:

```js
const Sample = ({ card = {} }) = > { 
  const {createdAt, title} = card;
  // rest of component
}
```

In this case, when `card` is `undefined`, it will default to an empty object and `createdAt` and `title` will be `undefined`.